# When can I use the Lucky Wheel again?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

It is possible to use the Lucky Wheel at Diamond Casino in GTA Online once per day, but I cannot determine when a new day starts. Does anyone know?

Comment: You can quit the game immediately after winning a shitty prize to get another spin right away, but I’ve been told Rockstar is onto people who do such things ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lucky Wheel is available 24 hours (real time) after your last spin. Unfortunately there isn't a timer available to tell you when that is. Personally I look at the clock when I spin the wheel and try again the next day at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

When you walk in the front door of the casino, it will tell you how long until you can spin again right above your mini-map.

This change was added in [GTA Title Update 1.50](https://support.rockstargames.com/articles/360052857133/GTA-Title-Update-1-50-Notes-PS4-Xbox-One-PC) (2020-08-11):

> When a player enters the Casino, they are now told how long they have remaining before they can spin the Lucky Wheel again.